# If there exists a function on a Riemannian manifold such that its Hessian matrix is the identity matrix?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, manifolds, hessian

In Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq 2$, the Hessian matrix of the function $\frac{|x|^2}{2}$ is the identity matrix. While on a smooth manifold $(M^n, g)$, do there exists a function on $(M^n, g)$ such that its Hessian matrix is the identity matrix? Welcome some examples, thanks!

Comment: Please define first what you call the Hessian matrix.

Comment: Sorry! Let $ \nabla $be the Levi-Civita connection of $(M, g) $. For the differentiable function $v$ on $(M, g) $, define $ \nabla v $  as the gradient of $v$.   Use $\nabla^ 2 v $ to represent the Hessian matrix of $v $.  Locally, it can be expressed as $ \nabla_ {i j} v=\nabla_ i\left(\nabla_j v\right)-\Gamma_ {i j}^k \nabla_ k v$.

Comment: It is known that the existence of a (non trivial) function satisfying $\mathrm{Hess V} = V g$ characterize the hyperbolic space (as far as I remember this is proven by X. Wang in "On the uniqueness of the AdS spacetime"). I would not be surprised if the existence of a function satisfying $\mathrm{Hess f} = g$ characterize the Euclidean space.

Comment: @RomainGicquaud:  Actually, there are many (incomplete) Riemannian manifolds $(M^n,g)$ that admit a function $f$  that satisfies $\mathrm{Hess}(f) = g$.  For example, let $(N^{n-1},h)$ be *any* Riemannian manifold,  let $M= \mathbb{R}^+\times N$, and let $g = \mathrm{d}r^2 + r^2\,h$ be the usual cone metric for $(N,h)$.  Then $f = \tfrac12  r^2$ has $\mathrm{Hess}(f) = g$.  However, $(M,g)$ won't be complete, and including a point for $r=0$ gives a complete smooth metric only if $(N,g)$ is a unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 4):

If a manifold is complete, the existence of the function $\phi$ such that $\nabla_i \nabla_j\phi = g_{ij}$ implies that the metric is flat and that in a  `flat'  coordinate system such that the metric is  $(dx^1)^2 +...+ (dx^n)^2$   the functions is $\frac{|x|^2}{2} + const$.

In order to show the flatness, observe that the vector field $\nabla^i\phi$ is the homothety vector field.

Indeed,
it is known that the Lie   derivative of the metric with respect to the vector field $v^i$ is given by
$({\mathcal L}g)_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}(\nabla_i v_j + \nabla_j v_i)$; substituting
$v_i= \nabla_i \phi$    inside proves the claim.

Now, the existence of a homothety vector for a complete Riemannian metric
implies that the metric is flat.

Finally, in the flat coordinates the equation  $\nabla_i \nabla_j\phi = \delta_{ij}$
can be immediately solved